# TFS Merge From Main to Dev

Tags: tfs, merge

I've got a team of 6 developers working on a big project that has a basic branch stategy. This has been working well for us, but I have a question about what TFS shows when you going into Source Control explorer and select Merge. Our branch structure is as follows...

- Main

  - Dev
  - Release

Developers works on their local machines and continuously check in and pull down from Dev. Continous integration is turned on and builds are pushed to a central dev server where internal testing is done when an item is complete. If tests pass, the specific changeset is merged from Dev to Main where a CI build is trigged and a scheduled build pushes the changes to a Test server each night where users can then test the new features. Once a week we merge all changes from Main into Release and publish the Release code to the production servers.

Again, all has been working well. My question is this...when all changesets have been merged from Dev to Main, TFS tells us if we try to do another selected changeset merge. Same from Main to Release. However, if I look at selected changesets from Main to Dev, all the merges we've done from Dev to Main show up in the selected changeset screen. When I look at a merge from Release to Main, there are changes there too, but not as many as from Main to Dev. We have been lucky enough to not have had to make changes in either the Main or Release branch so we have never had to merge backwards. Is this a workspace issue or what? In our scenario I'd assume there wouldn't be any changes that need to go from Main to Dev or Release to Main since all our changes have been done in Dev and then Merged from Main to Release.